# findFragmentByTag returning null

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-fragmentactivity

I am trying to allow my app to call functions from my fragment classes in the fragmentactivity. However I am having a lot of issues just finding the fragment. Right now I can find one fragment by id which I think is the fragment hosting the tabs. But when I get the child fragment manager I get returned a null. Can anyone help?

This is the fragment activity

```
package com.example.profileactivity;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TabHost.TabSpec;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTabHost;

public class ProfileActivity extends FragmentActivity {

    // Fragment TabHost as mTabHost
    private FragmentTabHost mTabHost;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_profile);
        mTabHost = (FragmentTabHost)findViewById(android.R.id.tabhost);

        mTabHost.setup(this,getSupportFragmentManager(), R.id.realtabcontent);

        mTabHost.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec("user").setIndicator("User",
                getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_user_tab)),
                UserProfileTab.class,null);

        mTabHost.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec("payment").setIndicator("Payment",
                getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_payment_tab)),
                PaymentInfoTab.class,null);


    }

    public void buttonClick(View view){
        FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
        if(fm.findFragmentById(R.id.realtabcontent) == null){
            Log.d("TABHOST", "didnt find fragment");
        }
        else{
            Log.d("TABHOST", "found fragment");
            //PaymentInfoTab paymentTab = (PaymentInfoTab)fm.findFragmentByTag("payment");
            //paymentTab.boom();
            if(fm.findFragmentById(R.id.realtabcontent).getChildFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("payment") != null){
                PaymentInfoTab paymentTab = (PaymentInfoTab)fm
                        .findFragmentById(R.id.realtabcontent)
                        .getChildFragmentManager()
                        .findFragmentByTag("payment");
                paymentTab.boom();
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.profile, menu);
        return true;
    }

}
```

This is the xml for the fragmentactivity.

```
<android.support.v4.app.FragmentTabHost
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <TabWidget
            android:id="@android:id/tabs"

            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0"/>

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="0"/>

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/realtabcontent"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>

    </LinearLayout>
</android.support.v4.app.FragmentTabHost>
```

Comment: The simple answer is that this Fragment instance cannot be located by the FragmentManager.  Probably because the Activity hosting this Fragment has been stopped or destroyed.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the tag on the activity's FragmentManager directly.

The complete reference of your example seems to be [this](http://thepseudocoder.wordpress.com/tag/tabhost/). Follow this example with more details, you will see that the writer keeps track of tabs and their tag.

Comment: I have. I can only find the id of the real tab content. I have also tried use getFragmentManager as opposed to getChildFragmentManager and both have been unsuccessful.

Answer (score 0):

I had the similar issue with fetching fragments after tab change which always returned null. Posting **Runnable** at the end of **TabHost** message queue did the trick:

```
tabHost.post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            Fragment fragment = (Fragment) getChildFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(tag);
            fragment.updateList(newList);
        }
    });
```